# What is the difference between MPI and MapReduce?

Tags: parallel-processing, mapreduce, bigdata

Can someone please elaborate the difference between mpi and mapreduce?

Comment: Which MPI are you referring to? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPI

Comment: imo, it's pretty clear from the contrast to MapReduce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an explanation of what MPI is, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40813750/is-mpi-a-paradigm-or-a-set-of-libraries). For an explanation of what MapReduce is, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982/simple-explanation-of-mapreduce).

There are some differences between both. MPI is a standardized API that has multiple implementations such as OpenMPI or MPICH. MapReduce is mostly a programming paradigm that has a vast amounf of implementations in different programming and database languages.